# Returning Only the Highest Value of a Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone explain how to fix this problem?

```
SELECT book_id, title, count(DISTINCT order_id)
FROM a_bkinfo.books
JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics USING (book_id)
JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id)
WHERE topic_id IN ("FCT", "POE")
GROUP BY book_id;


1077    Programming for Poets   2
1103    Selected Poems  34
1133    Leaves of Grass 4
1304    Stories of Discoveries  6
1306    Myths of SQL    3
1602    Goblin Market and Other Poems   4
```

I want only the row with the highest value on the right to be returned (i.e. "Selected Poems"). How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: What are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to get `max(count(DISTINCT order_id))` to return a number instead of an error.

Comment: The typical way to accomplish this is to sort by the count expression in descending order and then limit the results to one row. If you need ties then you might have to go with one of the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(order_count) from (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT order_id) as order_count
    FROM a_bkinfo.books
    JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics USING (book_id)
    JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id)
    WHERE topic_id IN ("FCT", "POE")
    GROUP BY book_id
) T
```

That's a scalar result so you should be able to add this to your original query on the select list if you want to see it appended to each row:

```
select ..., (
    select max(order_count) from (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT order_id) as order_count
        FROM a_bkinfo.books
        JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics USING (book_id)
        JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id)
        WHERE topic_id IN ("FCT", "POE")
        GROUP BY book_id
    ) as max_order_count
from ...
```

or you could use a cross join

```
select ...
from ...
    JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id),
    (
        select max(order_count) from (
            SELECT count(DISTINCT order_id) as order_count
            FROM a_bkinfo.books
            JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics USING (book_id)
            JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id)
            WHERE topic_id IN ("FCT", "POE")
            GROUP BY book_id
        ) T
    ) T2
where ...
```

Not sure which is the better option for MySQL.

This last option would return on the row(s) with the max value:

```
SELECT book_id, title, count(DISTINCT order_id)
FROM a_bkinfo.books
JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics USING (book_id)
JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id)
WHERE topic_id IN ("FCT", "POE")
GROUP BY book_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT order_id) = (
    select max(order_count) from (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT order_id) as order_count
        FROM a_bkinfo.books
        JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics USING (book_id)
        JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id)
        WHERE topic_id IN ("FCT", "POE")
        GROUP BY book_id
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would I put this in the original block so that it would return just the row with the highest number on the right? I tried comparing it in the HAVING block like this: `HAVING count(DISTINCT order_id) = select max(order_count) from (  
    SELECT count(DISTINCT order_id) as order_count  
    FROM a_bkinfo.books  
    JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics USING (book_id)  
    JOIN a_bkorders.order_details USING (book_id)  
    WHERE topic_id IN ("FCT", "POE")  
    GROUP BY book_id  
) T` but it returns an error.

Comment: Maybe I still mistook what you want. If you want to use `having` then wrap that whole query in another set of parentheses and from the T at the end. I'm not sure it'll work on MySQL but it should work on other platforms.

Comment: I just want to return the book with the highest orders (and only that book)--the one with the highest output for: `(count(DISTINCT order_id)`. Is there anyway to do this with MySQL? `HAVING count(DISTINCT order_id) = max(count(DISTINCT order_id)` returns an error for some reason, but `HAVING count(DISTINCT order_id) = 34` seems to work, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks again! I ended up using the bottom one. Makes a bit more sense to why it wasn't working now.